# Error trying to install seaborn through cmd without using Anaconda

Tags: python, seaborn

I have been trying to install seaborn through cmd without using Anaconda with the following command : `pip install seaborn`. I run this command in the cmd in the directory `C:\Python27\Scripts` and i get this error :

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ira6iy\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr
(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close()
;exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user\appdata\l
ocal\temp\pip-wzz50c-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-manag
ed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-b
uild-ira6iy\scipy\
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the wheel here and type `pip install seaborn‑0.7.1‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl` it should be easier for you search for it here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Although as cryptic as the error was did you install SciPy first?  That's all I can gather as possibly missing `pip install scipy`